# mysql how to NOT update datetime?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table where it has two datetimes, one of them is a 'completed' datetime, therefore, if it is NULL then the user has not completed.

I am trying to do an update, to update their mobile number.

How can i do it so it does not update the datetime?

currently if the datetime is null it gets set to the earliest possible time.

here is my query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE action_4_members
                SET `mobile` = '{$mobile}', 
                    `additional_txt` = '{$additional}', 
                    `misc_data` = '{$store_id}' 
              WHERE `id` = '{$member_id}'") or die(mysql_error());
```

here is my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `action_4_members` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `campaign_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `join_txt` varchar(160) DEFAULT NULL,
  `join_txt_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `additional_txt` varchar(160) DEFAULT NULL,
  `additional_txt_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `misc_data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=687 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An UPDATE statement will only affect the column(s) you specify (with one caveat):

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
   SET mobile_number = '123-456-7890'
```

The caveat is that if you have a `DEFAULT ON UPDATE TIMESTAMP` constraint set on the datetime column, the datetime column value will update to when the `UPDATE` statement was run.  If you don't want this, you need to correct the DEFAULT constraint on the datetime column.

Comment: Just added my table definition, does this still apply?

Comment: @Hailwood: Appreciated, but without the DEFAULT constraint then someone is triggering the datetime column population.  Columns don't populate on their own...

Comment: could php be doing anything by itself? (i.e pre-processing)

Comment: @Hailwood: Plausible, that'd mean an additional UPDATE statement in the PHP.  Comment out the one you know about & test to see if the column value changes.  If it does, look for other instances of `UPDATE action_4_members` in your PHP code...

Comment: odd started working perfectly randomly, 
will accept this as the answer as it provides a good tip :).